# How to use multiplication operation in game render delta time?

Tags: movement, game-loop, timestep

We are using **delta time** like this:

```js
private static final float SPEED = 200f; // Moving pixels in one second

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    myObject.vx += SPEED * delta;
    myObject.vy += SPEED * delta;

    myObject.move();
}
```

So I am using this update method to apply friction on my object:

```js
private static final float FRICTION = 0.98f;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //...

    myObject.vx *= FRICTION;
    myObject.vx *= FRICTION;

    myObject.move();
}
```

I know this is **wrong**:
`myObject.vx *= FRICTION * delta`

I want to use friction with *"multiplication operation"* not *"minus"*.

So how can I implement the ***delta time*** to my `FRICTION` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my assumption that you want your speed to lose 2% of its value every second, then this is a perfect opportunity to use the [exponential rate of decay expression](http://www.mathwords.com/e/exponential_decay.htm), which looks like this:

`A=Pe^(rt)`

`A` is the final amount you want (so, after 1 second, `.98(vx)`) and `P` is the initial amount. `t` is just time, so since you want the velocity to only be 98% of its value from the second before you can just plug in `1` for `t`, `.98(vx)` for `A`, and `vx` for `P` and solve for `r`.

This will get you about a value of about -.0202, but you can always store something more accurate.

So what your friction application code should look like is this:

```
myObject.vx *= Math.pow(Math.E, delta * -.0202);
```

If you did not know already, decimal numbers that omit the `f` are automatically initialized as doubles. `Math.pow` also uses and returns doubles, since they are more accurate. So you may want to have your velocity measured as a `double`. This will not likely make a very noticeable difference, but if you want accurate simulations, I recommend using doubles.

I have not tested this, so please leave a comment if you notice a problem, but I do believe this is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: This is a good method but if you use floats it won't be accurate, since some of the digits get lost. e^(0.016*-0.0202)=0.99967685222 so ~4 digits get lost

Comment: *this may only become important at high framerates because of smaller delta values => more digits that become relevant because the error adds up

Comment: @VaTTeRGeR I added a note about using doubles (2nd to last paragraph).

Comment: hmm i used it but yes, i am using "float" the speed is not lessening after a while, and object is still moving little speed. So am i use "-" instead of "*" for the friction? What is often used for friction in games?

Comment: You'll want a tolerance in which your speed stops changing, too since it's very unlikely that this will actually get you to 0.

Comment: my "stop speed" was 0.2f but now the speed is touring around 0.5.. and if i use "stop speed" to 0.5 then object is stoping suddenly (human eye is see it)

Comment: @Kumul The reason you were seeing little change is because 98% of 10, for example, is still 9.8, which is not much slower. You can always change your friction (you'll have to solve for `r` again, although you could probably automate that and store the value in a double) to fit what you want. Do you have any other problems or is it working?